# Conditional expectation of exponential rv

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $ X $~$Expo(\lambda)$. Find $E(X|X < 1) $.
I can find the conditional diaribution of$X|X<1$ and then evaluate the sum. But the question wants me to find the solution using law of total expectation and i don't know how to do it without using calculus. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}E[X]&=E[X|X>1]P(X>1)+E[X|X<1]P(X<1) \\
&=(1+E[X])P(X>1)+E[X|X<1]P(X<1)\end{align}

Where I have used the memoryless property.

Hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks! It is really difficult to remember all  the properties of a certain distribution while solving problems!

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you used the memoryless property?

Comment: memoryless property tells us $E[X|X>x] = x + E[X]$.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48496/conditional-expectation-of-exponential-random-variable for a proof.

Comment: But how do you get this from $P(X>s+t|X>t)=P(X>s)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot!...